# Ensure interface compliance in R S4

Tags: r, oop, interface, r-s4

I am currently developing an R package grouping all the functionality I am using in my lab projects. I am doing it, not only for the sake of it, but also for learning S4. I am experiencing now a conceptual problem. Imagine I have the following classes and methods:

```
setClass('A', representation(a='numeric'))

setGeneric('exec', function(x, y) standardGeneric('exec'))

setClass('B', representation(b='numeric'))

setGeneric('f', function(x) standardGeneric('f'))

setMethod('f', 'B',
      function(x) {
        return(42)
      })

setClass('C', representation(c='numeric'))

setMethod('f', 'C',
      function(x) {
        return(24)
      })
```

In the real case, just to provide some context, *A* is a class belonging to a hierarchy implementing the Command design pattern. *B* and *C* would be classes representing completely different things but with a common interface (in this case, the f method). Returning to the real thing, an example of the common *f* method would be nrow.

In other programming language, I think I would get along just by defining a method taking an abstract interface (declaring the *f* method) as an argument. Thus, every class implementing that interface could be passed as an argument to the command.

**Option A:**

Declare a method implementation for each of the classes.

```
setMethod('exec', c('A', 'B'),
      function(x, y) {
        return(f(y))
      })

setMethod('exec', c('A', 'C'),
      function(x, y) {
        return(f(y))
      })
```

**Option B:**

Implement a method with *ANY* signature, and then controlling if the class implements the given interface.

```
setMethod('exec', c('A', 'ANY'),
      function(x, y) {
        if (!hasMethod('f', class(y))) {
          stop('Y must implement method f!')
        } else {
          return(f(y))
        }
      })
```

If classes *B* and *C* were only a few, and I could find a common ancestor, I would have no problem with option A (taking the common ancestor or a class union as signature), but in this case there could be many classes like *B* and *D*, all in different hierarchies and with the only characteristic in common of implementing *nrow*, *ncol* and the *'['* operator.

I prefer the B option because I can explicitly state the interface compliance. But I do not know if there is a better idiom in R for this situation.

Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Personally I'd opt for option B (or a simpler variant that failed when f was applied inappropriately); there is no convenient way to specify an interface, especially across pre-defined classes. Class unions are weird (inserting a class into an existing hierarchy, over which you have no control), multiple dispatch is difficult to reason about and has a combinatorial explosion of possibilities. I'd also step back and make sure that I actually _need_ to support the complexity I'm designing, or whether the design is some abstract goal that sets the bar too high for the available tools / needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class union (see `?setClassUnion` for details):

```
setClassUnion("BorC", c("B", "C"))

setMethod("exec", c("A", "BorC"), function(x, y) { return(f(y)) })
```

Comment: I see the point, and that was my idea at first. But then, wouldn't I have to re-define the class union every time I add a new class? In the real case, classes B and C could be MethylSet (from the minfi package, inherits from eSet) or GenomicMethylSet (inherits from SummarizedExperiment), but I would like to be able to execute the method in every matrix-like class that I could.

Comment: @Fernandez: You are right. Or you could try an abstract/virtual class: `setClass(..., contains="VIRTUAL")` that would be the parent of your "B" and "C" classes and you implementing the methods for your abstract class.

Comment: I feel like I am having problems to explain my main concern. I could say that I would like to define the method interface according to a behaviour or contract, not a set of fixed class names.

Comment: I see , but wouldn't that be pretty the same as the class union? Besides, if I cannot touch MethylSet and GenomicMethylSet definitions, for example, because they are out of my scope, how can I declare them as children of the abstract class? It does not solve the problem of having to change the parent abstract class definition each time you add a new supported class, also.

Comment: You are right. If MethylSet and GenomicMethylSet are out of your scope you need to setup a class union for them (because you could not add a parent class to them). But I don't understand your second point. Why do you have to change the parent abstract class for each new supported class? Just add the abstract class as parent class `setClass("newclass", ..., contains="MyAbstractClass")`.

Comment: Just because I do not have access to MethylSet or GenomicMethylSet, so I cannot redefine from which classes they inherit. Anyway, I am going to accept your answer, because a class union could be a valid solution in another similar context. Thank you for your time. :)